# NSMutableArray of dictionaries from JSON feed insert new object for key iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I receive and array of dictionaries from a JSON feed and assign it to an NSMutableArray called jsonArray i.e:

```
jsonArray = [deserializedData objectForKey:@"reports"];
```

The feed looks like this:

```
reports =     (
            {
        address = "The street";
        email = "alex@blah.co.uk";
        "eng_id" = 1;
        "eng_name" = "Alex McPherson";
        "eng_thumb" = "http://someurl/image/1.png";
        form = Test;
        id = 59;
        lat = "51.1438330";
        live = 1;
        lng = "0.8693330";
        location = "17 Victoria Crescent, Ashford, TN23 7HL";
        name = "Alex McPherson";
        phone = 01233000000;
        rid = "A5C963-C95B-C3D639";
        title = "#A5C963-C95B-C3D639, Litter";
        tm = "2013-04-28 20:44:20";
        type = 5;
        "type-text" = "Litter";
    },
            {
        address = "The street";
        email = "alex@blah.co.uk";
        "eng_id" = 2;
        "eng_name" = "Rob Burt";
        "eng_thumb" = "http://someurl/image/1.png";
        form = Test;
        id = 122;
        lat = "51.1415000";
        live = 1;
        lng = "0.8715000";
        location = "38 Beaver Road, Ashford, TN23 7RP";
        name = Alex;
        phone = 01233000000;
        rid = "5A5C96-9072-6BAFA9";
        title = "#5A5C96-9072-6BAFA9, Litter";
        tm = "2013-04-28 20:35:56";
        type = 8;
        "type-text" = "Litter";
    };
```

what I would like to do is insert a new value for key lets say into this jsonArray: distance = "0.16km" but my brain is just not working tonight....

so the new jsonArray should looks like this with the added key value mentioned above:

```
reports =     (
            {
        address = "The street";
        email = "alex@blah.co.uk";
        "eng_id" = 1;
        "eng_name" = "Alex McPherson";
        "eng_thumb" = "http://someurl/image/1.png";
        form = Test;
        id = 59;
        lat = "51.1438330";
        live = 1;
        lng = "0.8693330";
        distance = "0.16km";
        location = "17 Victoria Crescent, Ashford, TN23 7HL";
        name = "Alex McPherson";
        phone = 01233000000;
        rid = "A5C963-C95B-C3D639";
        title = "#A5C963-C95B-C3D639, Litter";
        tm = "2013-04-28 20:44:20";
        type = 5;
        "type-text" = "Litter";
    },
            {
        address = "The street";
        email = "alex@blah.co.uk";
        "eng_id" = 2;
        "eng_name" = "Rob Burt";
        "eng_thumb" = "http://someurl/image/1.png";
        form = Test;
        id = 122;
        lat = "51.1415000";
        live = 1;
        lng = "0.8715000";
        distance = "2.13km";
        location = "38 Beaver Road, Ashford, TN23 7RP";
        name = Alex;
        phone = 01233000000;
        rid = "5A5C96-9072-6BAFA9";
        title = "#5A5C96-9072-6BAFA9, Litter";
        tm = "2013-04-28 20:35:56";
        type = 8;
        "type-text" = "Litter";
    };
```

basically I have a calculation that takes the long and lat from the feed and works out how far  the poi is from my current location of which then I sort the array by using a sort descriptor based on the distance key that I want to insert above. I have the code for this just stuck on inserting into the existing nsmutablearray above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the deserialized JSON array as an `NSArray` (not `NSMutableArray`). 
Then create a mutable copy of that array using something like:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [originalArray mutableCopy];
```

Then insert items into mutableArray.

Comment: Or I should say an array of key value pairs I suppose I should just use setValue forKey...

Comment: Yep silly me setValue forKey in the new array now I can sort array based on the distance.